# What is an optimal way of not repeating myself in the following code?

Tags: javascript

Following code works and i am simply looking for ways to not repeat myself as well keep to code clean and readable. Would love to see what methods that can be utilized to make it prettier.

```
const util = require("util");
const fs = require("fs");
const reader = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
const simpleParser = require('mailparser').simpleParser;

async function readFile(filepath) {
    try {
        return await reader(filepath)
    } catch (err) {
        return err
    }
};

async function getAttachment(filepath) {
    let file, email;
    try {
        file = await readFile(filepath);
    } catch (err) {
        return err
    }

    try {
        email = await simpleParser(file)
        return email.attachments[0].content.toString()
    } catch (err) {
        return err
    }
}

async function getFileName(filepath) {
    let file, email;
    try {
        file = await readFile(filepath);
    } catch (err) {
        return err
    }

    try {
        email = await simpleParser(file)
        return email.attachments[0].filename.toString()
    } catch (err) {
        return err
    }
}



async function main() {
    let attachment = await getAttachment('./mock-data/google-report.email')
    let filename = await getFileName('./mock-data/google-report.email')
    console.log(filename)
}


main()

module.exports = {
    getAttachment
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please change the title to be a description of the problem the code is solving instead of what you want changed. On a similar note, giving a little bit of background into what the code should do will really help people who want to review it. Other than that, great first post!

Comment: Only repetition I see is where you have 2 `try/catch` statements you could just have a single `try/catch` statement. You aren't actually doing anything other than returning the error message so you could actually pull the `try/catch` statements up to `main()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## DRY review

- You don't need to wrap `try` `catch` around `async function` or `promise`. The errors will all get passed onto the final `promise.catch`. So can remove all 5 try catches.
- The function `readFile` is just wrapping a promise and is completely redundant.
- The two functions `getAttachment` and `getFileName` are almost identical apart from the final return.
- The two file loads are of the same file that need only be done once.
- `filePath` as a string is defined twice, again only once is best.
- All you want is `attachments[0]` of the one email. So you don't need to store `file` and `email`.
- You use `util.promisify` and `fs.readFile` only once so no need to hold a reference for either.
- Assigning the variables `attachment` and `filename` can be done via destructuring saving another token.
- You are creating a module so keep variable names short, use the context to infer meaning.

The end result is

```
const reader = require("util").promisify(require("fs").readFile);
const parser = require('mailparser').simpleParser;

async function main(file) {
    const atts = (await parser(await reader(file))).attachments[0];
    const [attachment, filename] = [atts.content.toString(), atts.filename.toString()];
    console.log(filename);
}
main("./mock-data/google-report.email").catch(err => /*do something with error*/ );
```